# Error while accessing multiple files repeatedly

Tags: python, c++, file-io, resource-leak

I have a C++ and a Python code communicating with each other via reading and writing files in a directory, many times over. They also delete some of the files after reading the data. This is being done on Ubuntu 17.10.

However, after doing this sequence multiple times (>6000 - 7000 times), it comes to a point where I get the following error:

```
Couldn't open the directory: Too many open files
```

This error message is always delivered from the C++ code.

For the **C++ code**:

The data write is done using:

```
std::string opfilepath("/some/path/");
ofstream opfile;
opfile.open (opfilepath);
opfile<<"some stuff"<<endl;
opfile.close()
```

Number of files in a directory is counted using:

```
DIR* dirFile = opendir( path );
int count = 0;
if ( dirFile ) 
{
  struct dirent* hFile;
  errno = 0;
  while (( hFile = readdir( dirFile )) != NULL ) 
  {
     if ( !strcmp( hFile->d_name, "."  )) continue;
     if ( !strcmp( hFile->d_name, ".." )) continue;

     if ( strstr( hFile->d_name, ext.c_str() ))
        count++;
  } 

}
closedir( dirFile );
```

Reads file using:

```
std::ifstream file("/some/path");
if (file.is_open())
    {
      //do something
    }
file.close();
```

And files are deleted using:

```
boost::filesystem::remove("/some/file.txt")
```

For the **Python** code:

Files are written using:

```
f = open("/some/file.txt", "a")
f.write("some stuff")
f.close()
```

Files are read using:

```
fp = open(path)
lines = fp.read().splitlines()
fp.close()
```

And files are deleted using:

```
os.remove("/some/path/and/file.txt")
```

All the files are opened and closed in a modular way and synchronization does not seem to be a problem. But I keep seeing *Too many open files*, and always after a fixed number of iteration.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Does this run in multiple threads or processes? Is there any error handling around this code or is it possible that an exception is caught which doesn't close the file?
It is generally better to do file operations with proper error handling (using the ```with``` statement in python) and using a try catch block in C to ensure files are closed even in case of an exception being thrown between file open and file close.

Comment: Can you check you "ulimit -n" parameter, also provide the total number of file descriptors open by the process throwing error, you can do - ls /proc/<pid>/fd | wc -l. This will give you an insight of what is happening with file descriptors.

Comment: Which process gets the `Couldn't open the directory: Too many open files` error message?  The C++ one?  The Python one?

Comment: @rajatppn all file IO are nestled in try - except block (for Python) and try - catch block (for C++). No exceptions reported whatsoever. These are two separate processes, not multi-threaded.

Comment: @Yogesh: ulimit -n returns 1024.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: already mentioned in question, the error message is always from the C++ code

Comment: @Yogesh: yes, the number of files opened by c++ keeps increasing over time, I notice that now. But I have no idea where or how these files are being opened. All open files/folders seem to be accounted for (at least in the code)

Comment: @metsburg  keep checking output of command "lsof -p <pid>", it will give you the exact name of files left open causing the issue. As you said its a new observation that no. of fd is increasing with time, if no. of fd is increasing per iteration - consistently, then it is discernible that you should use gdb with breakpoints at relevant points in the iterations along with lsof use - to root cause the exact issue.

Comment: @metsburg alternatively you can run valgrind --track-fds=yes /path/to/cppBin, note that these are narrowing down techniques only.

Comment: @Yogesh: I managed to track it down. Thanks a lot. There was one rogue DIR* dirFile = opendir( path ); statement without the corresponding close statement. Has been resolved. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. P.S: I will accept your answer if you summarize your suggestions into an answer.

Comment: @metsburg good news, i posted the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Couldn't open the directory: Too many open files

This means that your process has exceeded the max open files parameter that was allocated to it, see that using ulimit -a, or ulimit -n. It could be possible that your process legitimately needs more fd's - if that is the case increase ulimit -n and start the process in the same shell, else follow the below mentioned.

If you want to see the trend of open file descriptors see it using  `ls /proc/<pid>/fd | wc -l`, it will give you insight on how the process is doing with open files.

This issue seems like file descriptor leak, so to take an easy stab on it use `lsof -p <pid>` to see all open files, which can provide useful hint.

If nothing works, and the problem seems convoluted then go with valgrind profiling and use track-fd=yes flag, `valgrind --track-fds=yes /path/to/cppBin`, to see exact stacks causing fd leak.